# how to store blocks of development node

Tags: substrate-node-template

I am using the substrate development node and each time I stop the node I lose all the data stored on the blocks.

Is there a way to store these blocks so that I can access them even when I restart the development node?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store the database on permanent memory rather than temporary memory for that you can use `--base-path` flag when you are starting your chain like:

`./target/release/substrate --dev --base-path "path where you want to store db"`